# When a demand contradicts law principles

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine someone is going to give an authority a big bribe to help him run a big project. The authority is a straight shooter and rejects his demand and overlooks the enticing bribe, because he thinks it contradicts the law principles. When he wants to deny the demand he should provide a reason (though he can do many other things e.g. arresting the guy etc.). I've made a sentence in my question, but I doubt how a native speaker would phrase it:

> - Your demands are outside the law.
> - Your demands are out of bounds of law.
> - Your demands are outside the boundaries set by the law.

For me, they all work, but how a native would say it is what I need to discover.

Comment: You’re overcomplicating it. Simplify. _Your demands are **illegal**_.

Comment: @J.R. :D I'm not going to overcomplicate something. I'm looking for an equivalent for a specific construction in AmE. Perhaps my example was not too clear or indicative. ;)

Comment: Your example was clear; I'm just saying there are much simpler ways to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your demands are outside the law. *(OK)*
>   Your demands are out of bounds of law. *(almost correct)*
>   Your demands are outside the boundaries set by the law. *(understandable, but verbose)*

Usually it is expressed as

> Your demands are outside the **bounds** of the law.
>   *your demands are unlawful*